# Is there a way to make bmps transparent?

Tags: c++, winapi, bmp

(Using WinApi) Is there a way to:

1. Make transparent pixels?
2. Somehow instead of using transparency just have the image dynamically get the background colors and textures, and fill certain Colors with those textures, For Example: If I had a video game sprite and the background color of it was white, could I somehow get those white pixels and fill them with the background colors/textures?

Comment: Maybe, but WinAPI is a painful way to do that.

Comment: Google "transblt" and take the first hit.

Comment: To Whoever Downvoted me: What can I do to improve this question?

Answer (score 2):

If you create a 32-bit bitmap, 24 bits of each pixel are used for RGB values and the extra 8 bits are used for an alpha channel.  Just set the alpha to 0 for full transparency.

When creating a bitmap that uses 24-bit or smaller pixels, the transparent color is usually indicated by the pixel in the lower-left corner of the bitmap.

Either way, creating a transparent bitmap is only half the equation.  Creating a transparent bitmap itself is easy, but you then have to render the bitmap in a transparent manner.  The Win32 API has [`TransparentBlt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145141.aspx) and [`AlphaBlend()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351.aspx) functions for that purpose, and there are plenty of online turorials and blogs that explain how to use them.